# Having problem with IndexOf in Visual studio - specific character

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, indexof

I try to find index of a word from string.

```
string str="This is test آبپاش .";
int index=str.IndexOf("آبپاش");
```

On visual studio index is -1, but you could to Ctrl+f in browser, both are same.

All I understand is about one character "آ","آ"
These are same on browser, but visual studio consider these as a different character. how could I manage it.

Comment: Maybe you should change encoding in config which accepts such characters.

Comment: One is U+0622, the other is U+0627 and U+0653. You need to [`Normalize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.normalize?view=netcore-3.1) your strings.

Comment: In dotnet core, it seems to work: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vFPYTh, in framework 4.7.2 not: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GIYByW

Comment: Which culture do you have in your OS?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever How come it works in dotnet core 3.1? I'd expect to have to normalize in both, framework and core?

Comment: @Fildor I've just in .net core 3.1 and it didn't work

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I try to use .Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD) on both string and it works. I have about 1000 line of code to check. is there any better solution ?anyway thanks.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski English(United states) and Persian

Comment: @Fildor I tested and it's not work on dotnet core. thanks.

Comment: Which version of core? In dotnetfiddle, it's Core 3.1 and it obviously is returning 13 (see above). I didn't try older versions, though.

Comment: @Fildor Your link is right, my Core is 3.1 too and don't know why it's return -1, Thank you.

Comment: @مهدینبوی, please try   int index = str.IndexOf("آبپاش"); I test it in .net framework, it's output is 13.